# HTML make view horizontally with scroll

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a vertical view with a scroll. This is how it looks like: [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9LF.png).

This is the code for view. I am using php to get the data, and html to display it:

```
<div class="ex3">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE ident ='".$currentName."' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') DESC";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
              $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;
                  echo '<div class="Nwrapper">';
                  echo '<div id="NformContent">';
                  echo
                  "<tr><br>
                  <td><b>{$row['date']}</b></td><br><br>
                  <td>{$row['name']}</td> <b>/</b>
                  <td>{$row['gsm']}</td><br>
                  <td>{$row['email']}</td><br><br>
                  <td><b>Info</b><br>{$row['pp']}</td><br>
                  <td>Date: {$row['transfer']}</td><br><br>
                  <td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aRS'>Update</a><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aR'>Delete</a></td><br><br>
                  </tr>";
                  echo '</div>';
                  echo '</div><br>';
              }
              /*freeresultset*/
              $result->free();
          }
      ?>
</div>
```

This is how my css code looks like:

```
<style type="text/css">

div.ex3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}


.Nwrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: center;
  /*width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;*/
  padding: 20px;
}

#NformContent {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

.aRS {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there somehow possible to change this code, to make the view and scroll goes horizontally instead of vertically, or do I have to proceed differently?

**EDIT TO QUESTION**:

I tried changing it up a bit. I added this code before the `<?php` script:

```
<div id="outer_wrapper">
<div id="inner_wrapper">
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.Nwrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /*width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;*/
  padding: 20px;
}
 
#NformContent {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

#outer_wrapper {  
    overflow: scroll;  
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper {
    width:6000px; /* If you have more elements, increase the width accordingly */
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper div.box { /* Define the properties of inner block */
    width: 250px;
    height:300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    border:0px grey solid;
}
```

It now scrolls horizontally, but the scroll is super long, even if there is nothing shows, it's just white background. I tried changing this line: `width:6000px;` to `auto` and/or `100%`, but that just makes it scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete width from div.ex3 and add float and also delete width from #NformContent and add padding
if you using bootstrap you can do this easily.

```
div.ex3 {
 /* width:100%;Delete This**************/
  float:left; /* Add This**************/
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}


.Nwrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: center;
  /*width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;*/
  padding: 20px;
}

#NformContent {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  /*width:50%;   Delete This**************/   
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

.aRS {enter code here
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at the **EDIT** in m answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Life will be easy if you using the framework to mockup the frond-end.

However, you could set your class like...

```
.ex3 {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: max-content;
}

.Nwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 200px; /*whatever you want it to*/
}

#NformContent {
    width: 100%; /*change 50% to 100%*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at the **EDIT** in m answer please?